# Azure python sdk: copy blob from SAS token

Tags: azure-sdk-python

i am trying to copy a disk snapshot to a storage account programatically.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

connString= "storageaccount connection string"
blob_client = BlobClient(connString,container_name,'test1')

copy_source_url =r"SASTOKEN"

blob_client.start_copy_from_url(copy_source_url)
```

I run in to this issue:

```
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I found out i can reproduce the error with this piece of code:

```
import socket
try:
    print(socket.getaddrinfo(copy_source_url,80))
except Exception, e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
```

I played around for a while, and found out i can get succesfully run socket.getaddrinfo with the base url (md-.blob.core.windows.net) but when i include the rest of the sas token it does not work.

Is there something i need to do to make the sas url work in python (I can download the file by using the link in a browser), or is it possible to let tell the SDK to skip this getaddrinfo?

Oh and i tried both port 80 and 443 by the way.

EDIT: This happens both when running the code locally, or running through an azure automation account. I am using python 2.7 to support  automation accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side and find there are something wrong in your code. Since we need to copy the content of a source file to the target file in storage, so we can't get the `blob_client` as below which your code shows:

```
blob_client = BlobClient(connString,container_name,'test1')
```

We need to write the content of source file to the target file("test1"), so we need the "**Write**" permission to it. So we should generate the SAS url of "test1" which contains "**Write**" permission (In my screenshot, I create a the target file named "file1.csv" for test and I select all of the four permissions).
[image]

Then use the code below to get `blob_client`:

```
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("SAS url of file1.csv which we generated above")
```

Now we need to generate the SAS url of the source file(I created a "file2.csv" as the source file) in storage, it just need the "**Read**" permission. And then start copy from the url.

```
copy_source_url = r"SAS url of the source file which we generated"

blob_client.start_copy_from_url(copy_source_url, metadata=None, incremental_copy=False)
```

After that, the code works fine to copy the content of the source file("file2.csv") to the target file("file1.csv"). Below is all of my code for your reference:

[image]